# Changing Bootstrap modal width - still has "hidden" width (inside for explanation)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap modal that i changed it's width to 50% and yet when i click outside the modal i can't dismiss the modal, it seems as if the 100% width is still "there".

For example open the normal modal and clicking outside it closes it since it takes up the exact space the ui shows.

when i set width to 50% the "closing space" by clicking outside the modal hasn't changed, it's as if it's still 100%.

how do i fix it? there is an example below that i made to show what i mean.

if you use chrome you can inspect the `<div class="modal-content" style="width: 50%;">` element and see the "hidden" width thing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#width_normal">Normal</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#width_half">Width 50%</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="modal fade" id="width_half" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content" style="width: 50%;">
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="modal fade" id="width_normal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `.modal-dialog` CSS (not `.modal-content`), if you want to have 50% of the original Bootstrap sizes you can divide default values by 2 like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 300px; /* Bootstrap default - 600px */
  }
  .modal-sm {
    width: 150px; /* Bootstrap default - 300px */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 450px; /* Bootstrap default - 900px */
  }
}
```

Comment: k thanks, i changed the width of the .modal-dialog. i had to give an absolute value (298px), i couldnt give it 50% for some reason. anyways thanks